# Issue with shuffling image to a hdf5 file

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, hdf5

I want to shuffle my image before putting it into the hdf5 file, but got an error in the computation. As a recent learner, I can't figure this out even afer reading the hdf5 documentation. Kindly guide me.

```
from random import shuffle
import glob
shuffle_data = True  # shuffle the addresses before saving

hdf5_path = 'Cat vs Dog/dataset.hdf5'  # address to where you want to save the hdf5 file
cat_dog_train_path = 'Cat vs Dog/train/*.jpg'

# read addresses and labels from the 'train' folder
addrs = glob.glob(cat_dog_train_path)
labels = [0 if 'cat' in addr else 1 for addr in addrs]  # 0 = Cat, 1 = Dog

# to shuffle data
if shuffle_data:
    c = list(zip(addrs, labels))
    shuffle(c)
    addrs, labels = zip(*c)
```

Error:

```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-19-4408536403db> in <module>()
>       2     c = list(zip(address, labels))
>       3     shuffle(c)
> ----> 4     addrs, labels = zip(*c)
> 
> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

Reference: http://machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/data_preparation/hdf5/hdf5.html#list

Answer (score 0):

The website gives Python 2 code. I am seeing your tag, are you using Python 3? You can convert it using

```html
2to3 -n filename.py
```